# How can I bind a single property of my OData service to a Form?

Tags: sapui5

Will you please tell me how to refer to the first tabular (and single) record?
There is a table with only one record:

```
    <Table items="{WaybillsPlaces}" mode="SingleSelectMaster">
        <columns>
            <Column hAlign="Center">
                <header>
                    <Text text="Number" />
                </header>
            </Column>
        </columns>
        <items>
            <ColumnListItem>
                <cells>
                    <Text text="{CoNumber}" />
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
```

How can I read the field of the first record without a table?

```
    <Text text="{WaybillsPlaces[0]/>CoNumber}"/>
```

I get a table reply, but I do not want to display it in the table - I want to display it in the form in text boxes, so there will always be one line in the response.

```
    <entry>
    <id>
http://xxxxx.xxx.local:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/LOGISTICS_SRV/WaybillsPlaces('4610103052')
    </id>
    <title type="text">WaybillsPlaces('4610103052')</title>
    <updated></updated>
    <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
    <d:CoNumber>46101030520001</d:CoNumber>
    </m:properties>
    </content>
    </entry>
```

**EDIT (As [@Denis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7715260/denis) description in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953192/how-can-i-access-the-first-table-entry-from-the-view#comment84953852_48971697)):**
I have an OData giving me the following entry

```
<entry>
    <id>
http://xxxxx.xxx.local:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/LOGISTICS_SRV/WaybillsPlaces('4610103052')
    </id>
    <title type="text">WaybillsPlaces('4610103052')</title>
    <updated></updated>
    <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
    <d:CoNumber>46101030520001</d:CoNumber>
    </m:properties>
    </content>
    </entry>
```

How can I bind the `CoNumber` property with a Input within a From ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give and ID to your table, get the table in your controller and call its 'getItems()' method. Then get the first object in the returned array:

**In your view**

```
<Table id="myTable" items="{WaybillsPlaces}" mode="SingleSelectMaster">
    <columns>
        <Column hAlign="Center">
            <header>
                <Text text="Number" />
            </header>
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{CoNumber}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

**In your controller**

```
onCertainEvent(evt){
  var oTable = this.getView().byId('myTable');
  var oFirstItem = oTable.getItems()[0]; // This is your ColumnListItem object in the first row
  var oFirstCellItem = oFirstItem.getCells()[0]; // This is your Text object in the first cell of the first row
  var sCellText = oFirstCellItem.getText(); // This is the text string in your first cell of the first row
}
```

**EDIT: bind only the first item in your model**

In this case you can do aggregation binding. For aggregation binding you need multiplicity greater than 1. So do property binding in yout ColumnListItem with `WaybillsPlaces/0/CoNumber`

```
<Table id="myTable" mode="SingleSelectMaster">
    <columns>
        <Column hAlign="Center">
            <header>
                <Text text="Number" />
            </header>
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{WaybillsPlaces/0/CoNumber}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

**EDIT: Data Binding options in certain events**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
    src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
   data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
   data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <!-- define a new (simple) View type as an XmlView
   - using data binding for the Button text
   - binding a controller method to the Button's "press" event
   - also mixing in some plain HTML
   note: typically this would be a standalone file -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
      <mvc:View
    controllerName="my.own.controller"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
    xmlns="sap.m">
      <Panel headerText="Table Panel">
        <Table id="myTable" items="{/WaybillsPlaces}" mode="SingleSelectMaster" select="onRowPressed" updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">
              <columns>
                  <Column hAlign="Center">
                      <header>
                          <Text text="Number" />
                      </header>
                  </Column>
              </columns>
              <items>
                  <ColumnListItem>
                      <cells>
                          <Text text="{CoNumber}" />
                      </cells>
                  </ColumnListItem>
              </items>
          </Table>
        </Panel>
        <Panel id="Panel1" headerText="onAfterRendering Data Binding">
          <Label text="First Item - Property binding:"></Label>
          <Input id="Input1"></Input>
          <Label text="First Item - Element binding:"></Label>
          <Input value="{CoNumber}"></Input>
        </Panel>
        <Panel id="Panel2" headerText="onUpdateFinished Data Binding">
          <Label text="First Item - Property binding:"></Label>
          <Input id="Input2"></Input>
          <Label text="First Item - Element binding:"></Label>
          <Input value="{CoNumber}"></Input>
        </Panel>
        <Panel id="Panel3" headerText="onRowPressed Data Binding">
          <Label text="Selected Item - Property binding:"></Label>
          <Input id="Input3"></Input>
          <Label text="Selected Item - Element binding:"></Label>
          <Input value="{CoNumber}"></Input>
        </Panel>
   </mvc:View>
 </script>


  <script>
   // define a new (simple) Controller type
   sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
    onAfterRendering: function(){
      var oTable = this.getView().byId('myTable');
          var oFirstItem = oTable.getItems()[0]; // This is your ColumnListItem object in the first row
          var oFirstCellItem = oFirstItem.getCells()[0]; // This is your Text object in the first cell of the first row
          
          var sFirstItemDataPath = oFirstCellItem.getBindingContext().getPath();
          this.getView().byId("Input1").bindProperty("value", sFirstItemDataPath + "/CoNumber");
          this.getView().byId("Panel1").bindElement(sFirstItemDataPath);
    },
    
    onUpdateFinished: function(oEvent){
      var oTable = oEvent.getSource();
          var oFirstItem = oTable.getItems()[0]; // This is your ColumnListItem object in the first row
          var oFirstCellItem = oFirstItem.getCells()[0]; // This is your Text object in the first cell of the first row
          
          var sFirstItemDataPath = oFirstCellItem.getBindingContext().getPath();
          this.getView().byId("Input2").bindProperty("value", sFirstItemDataPath + "/CoNumber");
          this.getView().byId("Panel2").bindElement(sFirstItemDataPath);
    },
    
    onRowPressed: function(oEvent){
          var oFirstItem = oEvent.getParameter("listItem"); // This is the pressed ColumnListItem object
          var oFirstCellItem = oFirstItem.getCells()[0]; // This is your Text object in the first cell of the pressed row
          
          var sFirstItemDataPath = oFirstCellItem.getBindingContext().getPath();
          this.getView().byId("Input3").bindProperty("value", sFirstItemDataPath + "/CoNumber");
          this.getView().byId("Panel3").bindElement(sFirstItemDataPath);
    }
   });

   // instantiate the View
   var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above

   // create some dummy JSON data
   var data = {
      WaybillsPlaces: [{
        CoNumber: "Item 1",
      },{
        CoNumber: "Item 2",
      },{
        CoNumber: "Item 3",
      }]
    };
   
   // create a Model and assign it to the View
   var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
   oModel.setData(data);
   myView.setModel(oModel);
   
   
   // put the View onto the screen
   myView.placeAt('content');

  </script>
 
 </head>
 <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
 </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT2: Bind a form input to a certain property in a OData Model**

Here I'm gonna use [Northwind](http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ALFKI')) OData service, for ease of use, but you just need to use your own model. I used the "Customers" entitySet (a.k.a "Customers" DB table), and the "CustomerName" property in this entitySet.

In your case (as per the given OData in the description, you should use the 'WaybillsPlaces' entity and your 'CoNumber' property. If you want to access one specific entry, provide the Key between parenthesis in the binding URL (in your case: `WaybillsPlaces('4610103052')`).

I highly recommend you to read more about OData binding in UI5 ([here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/44062441f3bd4c67a4f665ae362d1109) and [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e1b625940c104b558e52f47afe5ddb4f)). In a productive application, please set your OData model in the manifest.json file, to be sure that the $metadata call is done when the application starts, avoiding this way performance and many other issues.

[HERE THE SNIPPET](https://jsbin.com/bilolulota/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: My question is that I already have the answer that came - a table with one record. When loading the view, I need to scatter the fields in the form. How can I register in the form at once a call to a function (which already hangs in memory) and count its fields?

Comment: I still don't know if I understand you well... but I added multiple ways to get the content of a row which is in your model. Some how you need to decide which is your reference. if it is the table row, you need to wait until the bindings are completed to get the corresponding binding path in from your reference. Two ways to do this, onAfterRendering life cycle event, or updateFinished table event. Once the event is fired, do 'property binding' or 'element binding', whatever you prefer. Other way is clicking a table row, get the binging path of this row and do the element OR property binding

Comment: Added detailing to the description of the question. Thank you.

Comment: What you added is your OData, isnt't it?? Why are you talking about a table if you don't want to use a table?? what do you mean by 'I get a table reply' ?? Have you built a model with your OData?? If you have your OData, just build a model with it and then bind the property you want like in my examples

Comment: Can I make binding in the view itself without creating a model?

Comment: hahaha no... what do you want to bind?? by definition of data binding, you bind your certain properties to a model. The advantage of this technique is that the model will take the control when there is a data change, so it will rerender your UI objects binded to the changed data.

Comment: Seems like you are really confused with the concepts... and the way you are explaining your question is very confusing... Please tell me if the following statemet defines what you want to do: *I have and OData service like the one in the description, this OData has a property called 'CoNumber' and I want to bind this property with an input field within a form*

Comment: If this is what you want to do, I can help you... if this is not what you want to do, then I still don't understand you

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly, I apologize for the inaccuracy of the wording

Comment: There you have it in the **EDIT2** block of my answer. The snippet is linked in the jsbin